# In swift,"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"?

Tags: ios

```
let fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName("ArialMT", config.fontSize, nil);
[kCTFontAttributeName : fontRef];
```

`[kCTFontAttributeName : fontRef]` gives me the following error:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: And what exactly is that line of code supposed to be doing?

Comment: @SausageMachine  I want to use the dictionary to initialize NSAttributedString

Answer (score 1):

You didn't defined type of your dictionary. From your definition it is not clear what is dictionary type, this is ambiguity reason. You need to assign it to something to ensure that there is no type ambiguity. Also it is not a root error, as `kCTFontAttributeName` is a `CFString` type that is not `Hashable`, as result can't be a key of a dictionary, you need to convert it as `as String` first. The type of dictionary for `NSAttributedString` should be `[String: AnyObject]` So the proper answer will be `let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [kCTFontAttributeName as String : fontRef]`.

ps Also do not put `;` at end of lines, it is not required for Swift anymore and pretty often counted as bad style.

Comment: It can't be `[String: AnyObject]` as written, because `CFString` isn't implicitly convertible to `String`, but you've got the correct basic idea. It also cannot be `[CFString: AnyObject]` because `CFString` isn't `Hashable`. He probably wants to say `let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [kCTFontAttributeName as String: fontRef]`.

Comment: @robmayoff you are right, ambiguity was not a main reason of a error but just a misleading compiler warning.

Comment: @NikitaLeonov year,I know swift don't need ";", because i edit it in my mobile phone ,  I just use it to seperate codes. I want to use the dictionary to initialize NSAttributedString, so how to code the dictionary? thanks.

Comment: @Hai.Z I updated my answer with `NSAttributedString` related information.